# "recursively" grab all files in subfolders in S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I  need help to ‘recursively’ grab files in s3:

For example, I have s3 structure like this:

```
My-bucket/2018/06/05/10/file1.json

My-bucket/2018/06/05/11/file2.json

My-bucket/2018/06/05/12/file3.json

My-bucket/2018/06/05/13/file5.json

My-bucket/2018/06/05/14/file4.json

My-bucket/2018/06/05/15/file6.json
```

I need to get all files pathes with file name for given bucket:

I tried following method, but it didn’t worked for me (its returning not whole path):

```
public  List<String> getObjectsListFromFolder4(String bucketName, String keyPrefix) {
        List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
        String delimiter = "/";
        if (keyPrefix != null && !keyPrefix.isEmpty() && !keyPrefix.endsWith(delimiter)) {
            keyPrefix += delimiter;
        }

        ListObjectsRequest listObjectRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucketName)
                .withPrefix(keyPrefix).withDelimiter(delimiter);

        ObjectListing objectListing;
        do {
            objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(listObjectRequest);
            paths.addAll(objectListing.getCommonPrefixes());
            listObjectRequest.setMarker(objectListing.getNextMarker());
        } while (objectListing.isTruncated());
        return paths;
    }
```

Comment: If you want a good chance of getting useful advice, I suggest that you edit your question to provide a lot more detail around "didn't work for me" and "not whole path." Specifically, what exactly does this code do vs. what exactly you want it to be doing.

Comment: You can grab all files that start with a prefix using list-objects, then simply iterate over all of them. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#listObjects-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: Side-note: If you don't need it as code, you could just use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). It has a handy `aws s3 cp --recursive` command.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein , no, I need to use Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getCommonPrefixes()` only lists the *prefixes*, not the actual keys. From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectListing.html):

> For example, consider a bucket that contains the following keys:
>
> - "foo/bar/baz"
> - "foo/bar/bash"
> - "foo/bar/bang"
> - "foo/boo"
>
> If calling
>   listObjects with the prefix="foo/" and the delimiter="/" on this
>   bucket, the returned S3ObjectListing will contain one entry in the
>   common prefixes list ("foo/bar/") and none of the keys beginning with
>   that common prefix will be included in the object summaries list.

Instead, use `getObjectSummaries()` to get the keys. You also need to remove `withDelimiters()`. This causes S3 to only list items in the current 'directory.' This method works for me:

```
public static List<String> getObjectsListFromS3(AmazonS3 s3, String bucket, String prefix) {
    final String delimiter = "/";
    if (!prefix.endsWith(delimiter)) {
        prefix = prefix + delimiter;
    }

    List<String> paths = new LinkedList<>();
    ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucket).withPrefix(prefix);

    ObjectListing result;
    do {
        result = s3.listObjects(request);

        for (S3ObjectSummary summary : result.getObjectSummaries()) {
            // Make sure we are not adding a 'folder'
            if (!summary.getKey().endsWith(delimiter)) {
                paths.add(summary.getKey());
            }
        }
        request.setMarker(result.getMarker());
    }
    while (result.isTruncated());

    return paths;
}
```

Consider an S3 bucket that contains the following keys:

```
particle.fs
test/
test/blur.fs
test/blur.vs
test/subtest/particle.fs
```

With this driver code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String bucket = "playground-us-east-1-1234567890";
    AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("us-east-1").build();

    String prefix = "test";
    for (String key : getObjectsListFromS3(s3, bucket, prefix)) {
        System.out.println(key);
    }
}
```

produces:

```
test/blur.fs
test/blur.vs
test/subtest/particle.fs
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a new utility class — `S3Objects` — that provides an easy way to iterate Amazon S3 objects in a "foreach" statement. Use its `withPrefix` method and then just iterate them. You can use filters and streams as well.

Here is an example (Kotlin):

```
val s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
    .standard()
    .withCredentials(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider())
    .build()

S3Objects
    .withPrefix(s3, bucket, folder)
    .filter { s3ObjectSummary ->
        s3ObjectSummary.key.endsWith(".gz")
    }
    .parallelStream()
    .forEach { s3ObjectSummary ->
        CSVParser.parse(
            GZIPInputStream(s3.getObject(s3ObjectSummary.bucketName, s3ObjectSummary.key).objectContent),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
            CSVFormat.DEFAULT
        ).use { csvParser ->
            …
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is an example about how to get all files in the directory, hope can help you :

```
  public static List<String> getAllFile(String directoryPath,boolean isAddDirectory) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        File baseFile = new File(directoryPath);
        if (baseFile.isFile() || !baseFile.exists()) {
            return list;
        }
        File[] files = baseFile.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                if(isAddDirectory){
                    list.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
                list.addAll(getAllFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),isAddDirectory));
            } else {
                list.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this works for S3.  The objects there don't behave like ordinary `File` objects.